# Load class from vendor folder inside autoloaded class from a folder outside vendor

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a php application with a folder structure like this

```
-/app
-/vendor
-index.php
```

My "vendor/autoload.php" file is included in "index.php" file. When I call a class from vendor for example **upload()** in "index.php" file it loads without a problem. However if I call the same class in a method from a class inside "app" folder it shows class not found error.

Classes inside "app" folder are autoloaded like this

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4":{
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "verot/class.upload.php": "dev-master"
}
```

How can I call classes from vendor folder inside autoloaded classes in app folder?

**Edit:**

Classes from app folder are called in "index.php" like this

```
include("vendor/autoload.php");
$get_class = 'User';
require_once('app/'.$get_class.'.php');
$get_class = 'App\\'.str_replace('/', '\\', $class_name);
if(method_exists($get_class , 'uploadImage')) {     
 $class = new $get_class();
 $class->{ 'uploadImage' }();
}
```

Here is the **upload()** class being called in **User** class

```
namespace App\User;

class User{
 public function uploadImage() 
 {
   $file = 'user.jpg';
   $handle = new upload($file);
 }
}
```

Here is the error message

```
Class 'App\upload' not found in app/User.php:20
```

Comment: It is difficult to find the problem when we cannot see where these classes are being called. Can you please give us an example?

Comment: It can be many things. Please show us the code that works and the code that doesn't. You should also include the actual error message.

Comment: I have added how the classes are called and the error message

Comment: That's not where you call actually call `upload()` though. That seems like some odd generic code. I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: I further updated the code to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a namespace issue. You need to either add:

```
use upload;
```

under the namespace declaration in you `App\User`-file to import the upload-class or you need to use the full namespace to the `upload` class when using it:

```
$handle = new \upload($file);
```

You can read more about [it in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

*Note:* In the posted code, `$file` is undefined when you're trying to use it in `uploadImage()`-function.

*Note 2:* If you've included `vendor/autoload.php` in the top of your `index.php` (which you should), there's no need to include the classes manually in PHP. Composers autoloader will handle that automatically. Just to: `$user = new App\User`.

Comment: This worked! The perfect solution I was looking for! I had a hunch but didn't know what's the namespace to "use" upload class, Haha! Thanks a lot!